# How can I tell SQLDeveloper which version of JDBC to use?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to connect to an Oracle 9i server from my machine using SQLDeveloper. I already have a functioning version of SQLDeveloper 18.2 + Oracle Client 12 for more modern databases, but for this connection I want a separate older version of SQLDeveloper.

I've installed SQLDeveloper 3.2.20.09 in a separate folder on my machine and can launch it, but it defaults to finding the ojdbc6.jar file from Oracle Client 12. if I go to Help > About and select properties, the jdbc.library says jdbc.library /C:/app/client/product/12.1.0/client_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar

and if I try to connect I get the error ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

I tried putting the path to the SQL Developer 3.2 install first in the PATH variable, but no difference. Is there a way to tell SQL Developer which jdbc driver to use for Oracle ? (maybe in sqldeveloper.conf)

Answer (score 1):

The official answer is:

- use the jar (driver) we ship with the product OR
- use a Thick Client, and we'll pull the jdbc driver from an Instant Client or Oracle HOME on your machine

The 2nd option will work so long as you don't try to go back back or forward in time to the point that the software will recognize/support the driver.

In other words, you can't tell SQL Developer 18.x to use a 9i Home, we have a hard dependency to require at least a 11gR2 client (I believe, it could actually be a 12c based client which is required).

You'd be better off getting your data out of that ancier 9i Database and into a modern 12 or 19c Oracle instance.

> but it defaults to finding the ojdbc6.jar file from Oracle Client 12.

Sounds like you've managed to get a thick connection defined, go into preferences and disabled on the advanced page any reference to OCI or Thick, then it will use the jdbc driver shipped with SQLDev.